# React-native Javascript changes through codepush not getting reflected on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, code-push

My iOS App is not updating through CodePush.

I have added CodePush dependencies in my iOS App. Also I am able to successfully released an update to AppCenter using CodePush. But changes are not updating in my iOS app.

My React-Native module code is like below :

```
const codePushOptions = {
    checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
    installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME,
};
export default Dashboard = codePush(codePushOptions)(Dashboard);
```

And loading component from javascript in iOS Swift:

```
let jsCodeLocation = CodePush.bundleURL()!
let addRatingView = RCTRootView(bundleURL:jsCodeLocation as URL!, moduleName: "Dashboard", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions:nil)
```

Comment: Please update if anyone knew the solution.

Comment: How do you update the JS bundle? What is written in App Center: installed/ downloaded ? Have you followed entirely the set up as described in the docs?

Comment: I have followed the entire setup described in docs and then release my app to App Center using CodePush release command into Production. The release get successfully updated into the App Center but changes are not reflecting in my iOS APP

Comment: I faced the same issue. Be sure to insert the mandatory flag -m. After that it worked for me.

Comment: Where I have to add that flag? Can you please describe?

Comment: Look at the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue with iOS only. Be sure to insert the mandatory flag '-m' when releasing updates.

```
appcenter codepush release-react -a <YourName>/<AppName> -d Production -m --description '<Description>'
```

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Didn't work for me.